# Does shink_to_fit cause a rellocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

> Shrink to fit---This may cause a reallocation, but has no effect on the vector size and cannot alter its elements.

In my opinion, capacity() is always greater than size(), we can do it using

```
deallocate(finish_, endOfStorage_ - finish_);
endOfStorage_ = finish_;
```

So reallocation is never needed. Any wrong with my opinion?

Comment: A chunk of memory was allocated; how could you deallocate a part of it?

Comment: Thank you. It confused me before your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard library's allocator model does not permit partial deallocation of memory. If you allocate enough space for 10 `T`s, then you have a single allocation of that much space. You cannot remove part of an allocation; you can only deallocate all of it.

So if `shrink_to_fit` is going to change the capacity, then it can only do so by performing reallocation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer in short ..
Yes shrink_to_fit cause a reallocation

Requests the removal of unused capacity.
It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation if the request is fulfilled.
If reallocation occurs, all iterators, including the past the end iterator, and all references to the elements are invalidated. If no reallocation takes place, no iterators or references are invalidated.